# Excel formula to check for duplicate words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I require an excel formula to check if any words are being duplicated in any column in a row. My sample row is below columns separated by a ','.

**Column No**: *E221, F221, G221, H221*

**Column Text**: *Sam, John/Sam/Smith, Smith, Kyle*

Above Sam & Smith names are being repeated so the words should be highlighted in red.

Excel File Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D6PZWtbk_2IVEA4l1noFzKRFu0quXSTAewmL41xOnlo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If there is more than one name in a cell, are they separated with a '/' exactly as shown? Is there a limit on how many names can be in a cell? What have you tried?

Comment: Formulas can only provide an output (answer), they can not manipulate objects on the worksheet. If you want the words to be highlighted, then you would need to run a macro (code solution) or come up with a formula that you can use in conditional formatting (which would highlight the entire cell, but not the duplicate words).

What is it that you really need?

Comment: @rohrl77 ideally i need an indication that there is a duplicate name in the row and also which name that is. The duplicate names can just be shown in a cell and the highlighting of the entire cell will be an additional benefit, although it has to be a formula and not a macro.

Comment: @TomSharpe There can be upto 6 names in a cell seperated by / exactly as shown above. This is basically a names scheduling roster. Have tried a few examples from other similar stack exchange answers but the have not worked, will post them tomorrow as i don't have the file today.

Comment: OK. I think it would be quite a long formula because you would have to search for each of the 6 names separately, but it is do-able.

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html
They are using conditional formatting with CountIF(range, valuecell) to define rule, and set formatting based on rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does the job (assuming you have your data in B1:F1):-

```
=if(b1="",0,
SUM(1-(ISERROR(FIND(MID("/"&B1&"/",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",{1;2;3;4;5;6})),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",{2;3;4;5;6;7}))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",{1;2;3;4;5;6}))+1),"/"&$A$1:A$1&"/"))))
+SUM(1-(ISERROR(FIND(MID("/"&B1&"/",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",{1;2;3;4;5;6})),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",{2;3;4;5;6;7}))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",{1;2;3;4;5;6}))+1),"/"&C$1:$G$1&"/"))))
)
```

It extracts each name in each cell and tries to match it with all other cells *but* because it uses array constants you can't use it directly in conditional formatting: you would have to put this in (say) B2:F2 and base your conditional formatting on it, or else use an even longer formula.

It's an array formula, so need to enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Here is an improved formula. Previously I was matching cells to the left and right of the current cell: this one matches all cells including the current cell and subtracts the number of matches where the current cell matches with itself:-

```
=if(b1="",0,
SUM(1-(ISERROR(FIND(MID("/"&B1&"/",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",{1;2;3;4;5;6})),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",{2;3;4;5;6;7}))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",{1;2;3;4;5;6}))+1),"/"&$B$1:$F$1&"/"))))
-(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/",""))+1)
)
```

If you wanted a formula that you could use directly in conditional formatting, I think you would have to enumerate all possible matches for all possible substrings separately which is rather tedious:-

```
=if(b1="",0,
SUM(
1-(ISERROR(FIND(MID("/"&B1&"/",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",1)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",2))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",1))+1),"/"&$B$1:$F$1&"/"))),
1-(ISERROR(FIND(MID("/"&B1&"/",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",2)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",3))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",2))+1),"/"&$B$1:$F$1&"/"))),
1-(ISERROR(FIND(MID("/"&B1&"/",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",3)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",4))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",3))+1),"/"&$B$1:$F$1&"/"))),
1-(ISERROR(FIND(MID("/"&B1&"/",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",4)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",5))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",4))+1),"/"&$B$1:$F$1&"/"))),
1-(ISERROR(FIND(MID("/"&B1&"/",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",5)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",6))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",5))+1),"/"&$B$1:$F$1&"/"))),
1-(ISERROR(FIND(MID("/"&B1&"/",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",6)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",7))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE("/"&B1&"/","/","|",6))+1),"/"&$B$1:$F$1&"/"))))
-(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/",""))+1)
)
```

Comment: The name possibilities are limited so how would i do this through conditional formatting? Since this is an employee roster i have all the names. Can i save these names in a separate sheet and then check if the name repeats? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you had the names listed in separate sheet it wouldn't be too difficult to count how many times each occurred in the main sheet e.g.Sam (2), John (1), Smith (2). Then if you had a cell in the main sheet which contained a name with count>1 (like Sam or Smith), you would highlight it. It's really a different question though and maybe you should post it as such.

Comment: The sample data above is the same, its just that i have list a list of total names. Is there any way to upload an excel to the site?

Comment: Added a link to the excel file on google docs in the main question above. In the file the column in D should show if any duplicate names are typed in that row. The Names sheet has a list of employee names.

Comment: Just having a quick look at the link, I can't see any rows that have repeated names in them?

Comment: Have made changes, the first row has the name 'Sunny' twice & the second row thrice.

Comment: OK. I can't make this work in Google Sheets because of the limitations of conditional formatting, but have added a screen shot of the Excel version to your Google spreadsheet with the formula that I used in Excel. You need to paste it into Conditional formatting and add an equals sign in front. Apologies - the existing formula highlights blank cells if there is more than one in a row: will update my formulae in my answer.

Comment: No.. this is getting quite epic! I tested it in Excel 2010. I do have access to Excel 2003 at work as it happens - probably can use your list of names to do it but will involve some helper rows also am really busy atm so might take a while.

Comment: I tried it in excel 2010 but want to know how to apply it to all rows. Also it is highlighting cells with names in them where the names are not repeating in the row. Have uploaded the new file above in xlsx format. Applied the formatting on line starting with E221, have not added duplicates.

Comment: I applied it to the whole thing and the only time it goes wrong is in cell N99 where you've got  two // together. Need to modify with IF statement as shown in the answer to avoid blank cells and also change ranges to fit wherever you're starting.

Comment: Thanks its working. The range i put was D228:P228 and had to change the values of B1 and $B$1:$F$1 to D228 and $D$228:$P$228. Now the only problem that is there is how to apply this to each row?

Comment: Good! All you need to do is change D228 to the top left (D5) and $D$228:$P$228 to the top row ($D5:$P5) - note there is no $ before the 5's. Then apply this formula in conditional formatting to all your data ($E$5:$P$234 I think currently). Relative addressing will make the formula work for each row.

Comment: Great, glad we got there in the end

Comment: :) i also wanted to know if there is a formula which will check all the names in the row (from a list of names) and show the name which is not there in the row. Should i start a new question? Thanks

Comment: Yes, because (a) it's a different question (b) can show what you expect the results to look like (c) it's an opportunity to gain more reputation