# Excel: Index-Match using keywords and then SUM results (no VBA)

Tags: excel, indexing, lookup

I've got a sheet with a transaction list. It includes a description of the transaction and the transaction total cost.
I'm looking for a way, without using Visual Basic, to use comma-separated keywords entered in a cell to search for all matching transactions, and then give their total value.

For example:
[image]

B4:B6 are keywords for look up.
C4 should look up in range B10:B26 for all cells containing any of the keywords in B1 (tesco OR co-op OR waitrose), and return the total value of the corresponding values in Range C10:C26. In this case it should SUM C11, C16, C21, C23, C25.

It's important to note that it shouldn't be case sensitive.

Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, but it would be much  easier if you put Tesco, co-op and waitrose on separate rows and added the individual totals at the end.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there to be expected a `maximum` number of keywords being separated by commas?

Comment: I tried using SUMPRODUCT, but that only works for exact match and single string. INDEX and MATCH and Wildcard for partial match, but again, it doesn't work if I have variable criteria. The problem is that I don't really know how to create an OR statement for an index-match function, or separating a string to an array. And no, there shouldn't be a maximum.

Comment: Would an UDF be an acceptable solution? Just a single VBA function would do.

Comment: I'm not sure what UDF is, but I'm happy to check it out.

Comment: I have posted a formula solution to a similar type of question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388244/excel-formula-to-check-for-duplicate-words/30425174#30425174 but only practical if a limit can be placed on the number of keywords separated by commas (6 in this example).

Comment: Just saw your comment - 'there shouldnt be a maximum'; see my answer below - you will definately need to use a drag-across method of splitting out each word between a comma. For your purposes, anything without VBA is going to be pretty ugly (as in - a full sheet of background formulas splitting out each individual word between commas).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Array Functions. These functions operate similarly to "Sumifs" / "Countifs" / "Sumproduct": they perform functions normally designed to look at a specific cell, over an entire range of cells.

First let's deal with summing the total for "giffgaff" / "paypal":

In cell C5, use the following formula [As it is an Array formula, you must confirm by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER every time you edit the cell, instead of just ENTER] , and drag down to C6.

```
=sum(if(iserror(search(B5,$B$10:$B$26)),"",$C$10:$C26))
```

This looks at each row from B10:B26 (note that the entire column cannot be selected as an array formula calculates for all cells, even blank ones - so this drastically slows performance. You must specifically identify the rows you care about like this), and if there is an error when trying to search for the term in B4, that means the term does not appear on that particular row. If there is no error, it pulls the amount from column C. All of these rows are then summed together to get a single total.

Now to do the same for cell C4, you need to add in the complexity of first pulling apart each term which appears between a comma. I agree that @Tom Sharpe that you should probably do this in different cells to make it more clear what you're doing. This could be done by individually pulling terms between commas, and then having individual totals (which use the array formula above).

To do this most efficiently, I'd have use a helper column in column C, which will identify how many commas are in the text in column B, like so, in C4:

```
=len(B4)-len(substitute(B4,",",""))
```

This takes the length of B4, less the length of B4 where all commas have been replaced by blanks - giving the # of commas.

That formula can then be used to split out the words between commas, using the MID and SUBSTITUTE functions. Let me know if you need elaboration on how to do that. Once you have broken out the individual words, you can search with the Array function as above.

Comment: Thank u for the answer! I'd rather not separate the words into individual cells, but rather achieve the same result using a function. Individual cells would make the final spreadsheet very messy. I would love to hear how you use MID, Substitute and Array to search for the words, if you wouldn't mind. I'm happy to consider a VBA function to help achieve this.

Comment: If you want this to work with an unlimited amount of commas, you will need to either use (a) a VBA macro; or (b) have a scalable row next to each entry, which allows the words between the commas to be split up and then added separately. To do in anything remotely clean, the second option should probably be on a separate worksheet (or even 2, depending on how anal retentive you are). Take a look at @toms answer that he links above. that's how painful the formula is for 6 words only. Looking through his answer should provide you what you need to split out the words individually.